# Amazon Cloudfront not caching certain small number of static objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, processwire

Has anyone come across this issue where Amazon Cloudfront seems to refuse to cache a certain small number of static objects?

I've tried invaliding the cache (root path) several times to no avail.

I had a look at the file permissions of the objects in question, and they seemed all ok.

I've also gone into the Amazon Console and there are no errors logged.

You can see more details of this here :

http://www.webpagetest.org/performance_optimization.php?test=171106_A4_be80c122489ae6fabf5e2caadcac8123&run=1#use_of_cdn

My website is using Processwire 3 running Apache and a PW caching product called Procache.

Comment: There's nothing at the link you provided that indicates CloudFront is "refusing to cache" certain objects.  Please select one of the objects in question and explain how you are arriving at this conclusion.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, perhaps I'm misunderstanding how a CDN works? Would a website using a CDN deliver its static content from its own host as well as the CDN, or would it be exclusively from the CDN assuming the CDN was configured to deliver all static content and was fully updated?

Comment: For the content to be pulled through the CDN, the links in the HTML need to point to the CDN.  The test results page you provided suggests that this isn't how you are doing it -- some of your links are pointing directly to the main site.

Answer (score 2):

One of your issues is that you are not taking advantage of cache control headers on your objects. This is why you are seeing the message `No max-age or expires`. Look at this link to learn more about Cache-Control and Expires. Note: You should be using these headers even if you do not use CloudFront as the browser will cache certain objects also.

[Using Headers to Control Cache Duration for Individual Objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)

You do not indicate what web server that you are using. I have included a link for setting up Apache mod_expires to add cache control headers to your objects.

[Apache Module mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)

For static assests such as css, js, images, etc. I would setup S3 and serve those objects from S3 via CloudFront. You can control the headers for S3 objects.

The above steps will improve caching of your objects in CloudFront and in the users' browser cache.

Comment: Hi @John Hanley, I already have an <IfModule mod_expires.c> section defined with numerous ExpiresByType entries inside and also ExpiresActive on. 

I've added max-age directive and setting it to 8 days seems to have at least fixed the issue of Browser Caching issue I was having. Seems like the ExpiresByType entries had no effect without the Cache-control directives.

Comment: It seems like about 25% of the static content is being returned by the site and not the CDN, but as per above question to @Michael-sqlbot, perhaps I've misunderstood how a CDN works?

Comment: The percentage of CDN caching partially depends on how popular your site is. If there is not much traffic the CDN will not retain your files for very long. I do not know the exact formula.